# How to concatenate text across multiple lines in T_SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, concatenation, window-functions

I am working on the below problem in SQL Server using T-SQL, and have hit a bit of a barrier.

I am looking to concatenate multiple lines of text into one single line (text column below), based on a `personID`.

For example, if my raw data is:

```
PersonID   Text                     Line Number
-----------------------------------------------
A          The woman went to        1
A          the zoo,                 2
A          then went home.          3
B          A man went to            1
B          the aquarium,            2
B          spoke to                 3 
B          the fish,                4
B          then got an ice cream.   5
C          People love              1
C          football.                2
```

I need the output to be:

```
PersonID   Text                                                                        
Line Number
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A          The woman went to    the zoo,  then went home.                              1
B          A man went to the aquarium, spoke to the fish,   then got an ice cream.     1
C          People love  football.                                                      1
```

The number of raw data text lines varies from person to person, and I cannot find a solution to account for this (e.g. person A = 3, Person B = 5, Person C = 2).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?

Answer (score 2):

If you have SQL Server 2017 or later you can use STRING_AGG() as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE #Person (PersonID varchar(2), PersonText varchar(100), Line_Number int)

INSERT INTO #Person VALUES('A','The woman went to',1)
INSERT INTO #Person VALUES('A','the zoo,',2)
INSERT INTO #Person VALUES('A','then went home.',3)
INSERT INTO #Person VALUES('B','A man went to',1)
INSERT INTO #Person VALUES('B','the aquarium,', 2)
INSERT INTO #Person VALUES('B','spoke to',3 )
INSERT INTO #Person VALUES('B','the fish,',4)
INSERT INTO #Person VALUES('B','then got an ice cream.',5)
INSERT INTO #Person VALUES('C','People love',1)
INSERT INTO #Person VALUES('C','football.',2)

select PersonID, STRING_AGG(PersonText, ' ') PersonText
from #Person
GROUP BY PersonID
```

If not the then using FOR XML will do it as well:

```
SELECT PersonID, 
    (SELECT PersonText + ' ' 
            FROM #Person t1 
            WHERE t1.PersonID = t2.PersonID ORDER BY Line_Number FOR XML PATH('') ) PersonText
FROM  #Person t2
GROUP BY PersonID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t.PersonID,
    (
    SELECT
        tt.[Text] + ' '
    FROM
        my_table tt
    WHERE
        t.PersonID = tt.PersonID
    ORDER BY
        tt.[Line Number]
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ) AS text_out
FROM
    my_table t
```

Comment: You'll have a better experience posting answers if you include an explanation of how your code solves the problem from the question. And if there are multiple answers, why yours is different from the others. It will help the OP understand your solution, will increase your chances of having an answer accepted (and up-voted), and will help future readers get value from your answer.

Comment: Thank you guys.Why are we able to use the outer query personid (t.personid) in the subquery where clause? Would this not need a join or something in the subquery?

Comment: Codingguy1, this is called a correlated subquery. the join is accomplished with t.PersonID = tt.PersonID